# Cron job issue at centos server

Tags: php, cron

There are many processess executed via cron job at our production server. Time decided to run process is after every 50 minutes.

Crontab file entry-:

```
*/50 * * * * /usr/bin/php  /webuser/production/class/abc.php
*/50 * * * * /usr/bin/php  /webuser/production/class/abc_1.php
*/50 * * * * /usr/bin/php  /webuser/production/class/abc_2.php
```

But when we check cron logs there is error as shown below:

```
Oct 22 12:56:01 prodserver CROND[40603]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php  /webuser/production/class/abc.php )
Oct 22 12:56:01 prodserver CROND[40604]: (CRON) EXEC FAILED (/usr/sbin/sendmail): No such file or directory

Oct 22 12:56:14 prodserver CROND[40602]: (root) MAIL (mailed 1911 bytes of output but got status 0x0001#012)
```

When we run same process as stand alone on command line /usr/bin/php  /webuser/production/class/abc.php it runs successfully.

We browsed over internet and found an answer on stackoverflow by one user saying just make the process which tend to get executed by cron job to write its output in some random file, so we did as shown below:

```
/usr/bin/php  /webuser/production/class/abc.php >> /somerandomfolder/log_cron_check
```

By doing this the process get executed without an error via cron job. Though cron job executed by placing >> this but the time of execution is random its not what is mentioned in crontab. Cron was mentioned to run after 50 minutes but our database and cron log showing it runs unexpectedly after 10 minutes.

```
queue_start_time
2022-10-22 12:20:01
2022-10-22 12:30:01
```

Please suggest where we are doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the cron log shows the same time as the last one? I doubt this because your last log shows a backdate to the cronjob above.

Comment: FYI this value `*/50` won't run the script you expected (every 50 minutes), it schedules at minutes 0 and 50.

Comment: How can i set it to run after every 50 minute. These are two different logs, 1. is from /var/log/cron while later one is from DB record.

Comment: You can't, are you really need 50 minutes?

Comment: @champs You could store last execution in DB and if it is < 50 minutes kill the process, if greater than 50 minutes run the process and update last run time. Run every 10 minutes with this approach... running hourly though is probably easier

Answer (score 0):

You get an error in the crontab logs because you don't have sendmail installed.
How is that related even if you don't use sendmail in your PHP code?
crontab has an implementation to send alert notifications when finishes a job.
from crontab man page

> If standard output and standard error are not redirected by commands executed from the crontab entry, any generated output or errors shall be mailed, via an implementation-defined method, to the user.

As mentioned you need to redirect both stdout and stderr, you have only tried to redirect the stdout.
Something like this should solve it.

```
*/50 * * * * /usr/bin/php /webuser/production/class/abc.php &>/tmp/log
```

Comment: No we don't need to output anything, it was said in one of the solution thats why i had tried it only. @OZ_  */50 * * * * works alternatviely means one time it executes after 50 minutes but again it get execute after 10 minutes, we have no idea why and how its happening to us.